# Spring switch property value

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-el

Let's say I've a property file where I've the following properties

**name= harry,andy,robert**

**email.harry = harry@xyz.com**

**email.andy = andy@xyz.com**

**email.robert = robert@xyz.com**

The requirement is to display the e-mail addresses by filtering the name property.

So in the above case all the e-mail addresses should be displayed.

Let's say if in future if I remove "robert" from name property, then only the email addresses of harry and andy should be displayed.

is there a way to do the same using spring dependency injection?

P.S.: I want to make the name property configurable. I dont want to add a new bean property everytime.

Comment: displayed where?. Where are these properties read?

Comment: This is possible. Create a class and annotate `@Value("${my.property.name}")`.In view  check whether is not null according to that show.

Comment: @Value("${my.property.name}") will fetch me the value of name property. But how can I fetch the corresponding e-mails for the name?

Comment: @Sandy you better split the string  and suppose if the names have only one lets say ..harry. check against the the list of email which contains the name harry . if there you send it otherwise don't send.got it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the @ConfigurationProperties("email") annotation on your component to bind to the name and a list of emails. You'll have to rejig your properties a bit:

```
Properties:

email.names = harry,andy,robert
email.addresses.harry = harry@xyz.com
email.addresses.andy = andy@xyz.com
email.addresses.robert = robert@xyz.com
```

Your class:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("email") // prefix email, find email.* values
public class AppProperties {

    private String names;
    private List<String> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
```

and Spring should bind it all for you. Have a look at this tutorial that says more or less the same:  https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/

Spring Boot only though, but yet another good reason to use it if you aren' already.

Comment: Thanks.But the requirement is a bit different....let say....the property email.names contains only harry.then the email should only be sent to harry and not to andy and robert.
Let say at a later point,I thought of adding harry,andy. Then the email should be sent to both harry and andy but not to robert.
Is there a way to bind the name and email at runtime?